# Bootstrap column width - auto sizing when other containers are removed

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a few graphs displaying on a page. The top row has 4 graphs, using

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
```

The next row has two graphs using

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
```

Each DIV has a close link that removes it from the page.

Is it possible when closing a DIV, that the others will automatically resize to use the 12 column spacing ?

4 graphs, close 1 and it changes from col-md-3 to col-md-4, close another and it changes to col-md-6, close another and it changes to col-md-12.

and for the bottom row, close 1 of the 2 graphs and the other changes to col-md-12 ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to replace the classes if you give your divs id's.

```
document.getElementById("MyID").className =
document.getElementById("MyID").className.replace(/\bcol-md-3\b/,'col-md-4');
```